# How to allow a specific portion of my table to be responsive to clicks in html?

Tags: javascript, html

Consider the following set of codes I have:

```
<table>             
                    <tr id='changeOnClick'>
                    <td></td>
                    <td id="metre_" >Metre</td>
                    <td id="centimetre_">Centimetre</td>
                    <td id="fermi_" >Fermi</td>
                    </tr></table>
```

Now the JavaScript I have is something like this:

```
            document.getElementById('chooseid').onclick = start;
            function start(){
            \\Do something...
}
```

But, as you see, I don't want the first cell, that is an empty `<td>` to get affected by this `start()` in my JavaScript code. So, what changes shall I do to fix this? Do I need to consider taking all the remaining cells of the row into another container?

In fact, I tried this:

```
<table>             
                    <tr id='changeOnClick'>
                    <td></td>
                    <div id='changeOnClick'>
                    <td id="metre_" >Metre</td>
                    <td id="centimetre_">Centimetre</td>
                    <td id="fermi_" >Fermi</td>
                    </div>
                    </tr></table>
```

But unfortunately, it did not work. Help!

Comment: First: a `<div>` is not a valid child of a `<tr>` tag. Next: I would add the click listener to all the `<td>` elements except the first in each row: `document.querySelectorAll("td:not(:first-child)").forEach(td => td.addEventListener("click",start));`

Comment: There's some info missing in your description, because if you're adding a click event to an element by id then you can click that first td all day and nothing will happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply use some inline css to disable clicking on that element such as

```html
<td style="pointer-events:none;"></td>
```

Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

```html
<table>
   <tr id='changeOnClick'>
      <td style="pointer-events:none;"></td>
      <td id="metre_" >Metre</td>
      <td id="centimetre_">Centimetre</td>
      <td id="fermi_" >Fermi</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```